# Flutter background video not played

Tags: flutter, video-player

I have a 2360x2360 video. I wanna make it as a background video, it need this size beacause of the supporting screen size of Galaxy Fold and I don't want to auto scaled the video, since it is not my expected screen of video. I currently used below code, however I can't see the video, the background is grey.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = VideoPlayerController.asset("assets/video/login.mp4")
      ..initialize().then((_) {
        controller.play();
        controller.setLooping(true);
        setState(() {});
      });
  }


  ClipRect(
          child: OverflowBox(
              maxWidth: double.infinity,
              maxHeight: double.infinity,
              child: FittedBox(
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  child: Container(
                      width: size.width,
                      height: size.height,
                      child: VideoPlayer(controller))))),
```

Hope the video can base on the screen size crop the video and supporting all devices screen size